# Getting matrix error cin>>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this code works well, but I get a black screen without output
When I remove `cin>>` it works well, but without `cin>>` this program useless.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int x [5];
    int i;
    int sum;
    for(i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    cin>>x[i];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            cout<<x[i];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            sum=sum+x[i];
            cout<<sum ;
int z;
cin>>z;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `cin` is supposed to do?

Comment: I guess you are running it from an IDE. Right? It is working fine It is just closing too fast.

Comment: Did you actually give some input?

Comment: cin supposed enter x[i] thats must be x[0] then add then x[1] ..

Comment: yea i forgot .. sum=0

Comment: @user2335382 But you should expect there to be no output until you start giving some input. You need to type in 5 numbers as input to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include <iostream>`

```
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int x [5]={};
  int i;
  int sum=0;
  cout << "please enter five integers (seperated with spaces) and press return: ";
  for(i = 0;i < 5;i++){
    cin>>x[i];
  }
  cout << "the integers you entered are: ";
  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<x[i]<<" ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << " the culmulative sums of those integers are: ";
  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        sum=sum+x[i];
        cout<<sum << endl;       
  }
  int z;
  cout << "enter another integer" << endl;
  cin>>z;
  cout << "ok i'm ending the program without doing anything with the last int you entered" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about cin>> in the first for loop, then the cin>> is used to get inpur from console.
You are supposed to give it an input, press enter. then your array will be initialized. I think you don't appreciate the whole working of cin>>.